# Type mismatch: inferred type is GroupsFragment but Context! was expected

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

I'm learning how to parse a JSON and using the data to put it in a recyclerview list and I am doing it in a fragment. This is giving lots of headhaches, and kinds of errors. The first one is the Context! this is the GroupFragment.kt file content:

```
package com.locos.riders

import android.graphics.Color
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.Button
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.fragment_groups.*
import com.locos.riders.UserListAdapter

class GroupsFragment : Fragment() {

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_groups, container, false)
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        userlist.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
        userlist.adapter = UserListAdapter


    }


}
```

When I run this, I get the Type mismatch: inferred type is GroupsFragment but Context! was expected.

In my UserListAdapter.kt I am trying to load userlist_row and i also cannot find this layout resource, even that the file is created and in layout/ folder:

```
package com.locos.riders

import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.userlist_row.view.*

class UserListAdapter: RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomViewHolder>() {

    // number of items
    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return 3
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup?, viewType: Int): CustomViewHolder {
        val layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent?.context)
        val cellForRow = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.userlist_row, parent, false)
        return CustomViewHolder(cellForRow)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: CustomViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.view.listTitle?.text = "123"
    }

}

class CustomViewHolder(val view: View): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {

}
```

Comment: try LinearLayoutManager(context)

Comment: It worked! but now Classifier 'UserListAdapter' does not have a companion object, and thus must be initialized here

Comment: userlist.adapter = UserListAdapter()

Answer (score 0):

You have some typo errors, usually can be fixed by reading the errors.

Here is the solution of those errors:

```kotlin
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    userlist.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context) // <- context == getContext() in java
    userlist.adapter = UserListAdapter() // <- put parentheses over here
}
```